# ContextRegistry rootContextName is always null or empty

Tags: c#, .net, spring.net

Using Spring.NET IoC to inject dependency objects into properties.  The app is an Outlook plug-in.

The code:

```
IApplicationContext ctx = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
this.Property = (MyObject)ctx.GetObject("MyObject");
```

The Config:

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core"/>
      <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <spring>
    <context>
      <resource uri="config://spring/objects"/>
    </context>
    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
      <description></description>
      <!--Business Logic Layer Binding Objects-->
      <object name="MyObject" 
              type="Quadrant2.MSCRM.Recruit.OfficeAddins.Toolbar.BusinessLogic.Q2_Win_SearchClient_Logic, Quadrant2.MSCRM.Recruit.OfficeAddins.Toolbar.BusinessLogic">
        <property name="SearchClientDAL" ref="DAL_SearchClient"/>
      </object>
<!-- snip -->
```

This code was running fine for around 2 years and then we upgraded a few assemblies around Outlook to run in Outlook 2010 and some Ribbon modifications - nothing that should affect Spring.NET I think.

Started getting the "The context name passed to the GetContext method cannot be null or empty" exception thrown on the `GetContext();` call.  On closer inspection I noted that the `rootContextName` is null - fair call, explains the exception I thought.

Also noted that the code would run fine during debug but fail once it runs outside debug.  Checked dll's, dependencies and configs are all in the right place during install.

"Force fed" `GetContext();` a context name, "spring.root" as per debug session `rootContextName` value, and the exception goes away but `IApplicationContext` is returned null.

Any ideas or obvious issues here?